# LocalSessionFactoryObject - MappingResources - Path to the hbm file

Tags: c#, nhibernate, spring.net, mapping-resources

The project structure is:

[image]

Now I am trying to create a bean `NHibernateSessionFactory` as:

```xml
<object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="MappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>EMSApplication.Domain/EMSApplication.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
    <dictionary>
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"/>
        <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
        <entry key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate"/>
        <entry key="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <entry key="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <entry key="cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </dictionary>
    </property>

    <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
</object>
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
Error creating context 'spring.root': file [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\EMSApplication.Domain\EMSApplication.hbm.xml] cannot be resolved to local file path - resource does not use 'file:' protocol.
```

Now the project is on D drive, I am wondering why this is pointing C drive?

Also how can I add the specified hbm file in the mapping resource? This file is set as 'Embedded Resource'.

Is there any way to specify a directory here to scan for the multiple hbm files?

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using a protocol identifier (e.g. `file://` or `assembly://`) in your resource name, so Spring uses the default file protocol. It tries to resolve the hbm file from the location where the web app is running (the devserver path), *not* where it's files are stored, which you seem to expect.

To reference a file in your website use a `~` to identify the root of your web site, e.g. `<value>file://~/EMSApplication.Domain/EMSApplication.hbm.xml</value>`. But make sure the file is copied, which might not be the case, since you have set it to embedded resource (why?).

Consider the following improvements, they'll make your live more easy:

- move the code in your folders `dao`, `domain` and `NHibernate` to a separate assembly (a class library project that is referenced from your web application) named `Your.AssemblyName`.
- The session factory also supports specifying mapping assemblies to scan, so that you don't have to specify each file - see the docs on [setting up a session factory using spring.net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup). Specify `Your.AssemblyName` in the mapping assembly list:

```xml
<object id="MySessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
  <property name="MappingAssemblies">
    <list>
      <value>Your.AssemblyName</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="HibernateProperties">
  <!-- snip -->
</object>
```

And check out [the NHibernate example in the spring docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/nh-quickstart.html) - it's very applicable to the questions you are raising here.